# Error when reading core config file: Unsupported Config Type

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, artifacts

I am trying to pass in the channel configuration transaction artifact to the order-er  using the command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile 
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

But I get an error:

```
2018-03-17 20:55:21.380 GMT [main] main -> ERRO 001 Fatal error
 when initializing core config : error when reading core 
config file: Unsupported Config Type ""
```

What does this error mean? and how can I fix it?

Using `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                              NAMES
5c27fce33911        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest                                                                          "/bin/bash"              3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                                    cli
aabf72f81352        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                 0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
73ddcafb5ce6        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest                                                                        "orderer"                3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
205448f5479a        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                 0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
4e5ba2999f54        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                 0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
fcc6b25b6422        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest                                                                           "peer node start"        3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                 0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
2f1536ffe265        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0-5c906e402ed29f20260ae42283216aa75549c571e2e380f3615826365d8269ba   "chaincode -peer.add…"   24 hours ago        Exited (255) 3 minutes ago                                                      dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0
6ae48101bc34        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                    "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   24 hours ago        Exited (255) 3 minutes ago   0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                             ca.example.com
dc9e5bb3cc8e        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   24 hours ago        Exited (255) 3 minutes ago   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp         couchdb
```

this is the log of orderer.example.com
[image]

Comment: to find the logs you can first do `docker ps -a` and then `docker logs container id`

Comment: I have added the log of orderer.example.com,also added docker ps -a at the end of the question.Hope this helps and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Well your ca.example.com is already down and it has to be up and running.

Comment: how do I fix that?

Comment: I don't have permanent solution but remove -d flag while spinning up the docker containers.

Comment: removing -d just shows the logs

Comment: docker-compose -f $COMPOSE_FILE -f $COMPOSE_FILE_COUCH -f $CA_FILE up

Comment: go in the folder where you have configuration files and type FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD. thats the only 2 reason that you can have this type of error. i dont see any other reason why there is config issue. or may be there is type in your configuration file.

Comment: Is it because I forgot to specify env variables?CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

Comment: Nice, that what this error was all about missing something in config file :). Glad you found the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be inside the CLI container to execute the `peer channel create` command.

You will enter the CLI container using the `docker exec` command:

> docker exec -it cli bash

If successful you should see the following:

> root@0d78bb69300d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#

Over there, you should run the `peer channel create` command like this:

> root@0d78bb69300d:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

Before running this command, please note that you should also run commands for creating environment variables for CHANNEL_NAME and other Environment variables for PEER0 **within this CLI Container**.

Answer (score 3):

export `FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD`. it will resolve this issue.

Comment: I did that but doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: can you please add the logs for orderer.example.com

Comment: how can I find the logs? sorry I am kinda new to this.

Comment: I think the problem is that in the tutorial where I build my first network I got to the part where I start the network and there is a command which i didnt do because i don't understand how it works: 
         working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

Comment: I tried to ignore export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD and use the command line option "-configPath ./configtx.yaml" which seems like it should work. cryptogen supports command line option for crypto-config.yaml

Answer (score 3):

This is the error you get when the core.yaml is not found. Like the Mukesh mentioned above, running command within the CLI Container will not throw the Error.

See [this link](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-10523) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try running this command: echo $FABRIC_CFG_PATH

Whatever value you get, can you navigate to that directory and confirm if you can see the configtx.yaml file in there.

From the docs [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html), it says the error is as a result of inappropriately setting the value of that variable.

Comment: I exported FABRIC_CFG_PATH in /c/Users/$name/fabric-samples/first-network and configtx.yaml is in that folder so I don't know what the problem could be.