# Hyperledger Fabric peer error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm running Hyperledger on an **ubuntu** virtual machine. After installing hyperledger prerequisites and binaries, when I try to execute the 'peer' command, it returns:

```
[main] main -> ERRO 001 Fatal error when initializing core config : 

error when reading core config file: Unsupported Config Type "".
```

On my machine (MAC) the command runs perfectly and displays the command usage description.

Any ideas? I tried with 3 virtual machines and all result to to the same error.

Comment: did you provide the configuration option ?export  FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD

Comment: Yes, i did, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please refer to this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341851/error-when-reading-core-config-file-unsupported-config-type#comment86198928_49341851)

Possible solutions :

1. Set Path `FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD`
2. Error in following configuration

   CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
3. There is typo mistake in your code.

Comment: The problem was somewhere in the environment variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure FABRIC_CFG_PATH environment variable is set to a directory. In the Hyperledger Fabric docker containers, it is usually set to /etc/hyperledger/fabric.